# suddenly TS lint in VSC became silently broken

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsx, virtual

i use Linux Mint 19.1 and VSC (both: .deb and flatpack version) 1.41.1 (2019-12-18)
I use TSlint plugin in vsc, everything worked till yesterday then suddenly no more any underline or ts error in that files where i used any virtual element (JSX) but TS error work in other files where no JSX...

i don't use tslint.json (its worked in 2 day ago well with same settings).
i tried uninstall and reinstall the plugin (also disable and enable option used too) but issue still exist and i don't know why.
i use with my own VDOM (virtual dom) object/builder/handler;

https://github.com/shadowvzs/petraJS/blob/master/project/src/core/VDom.ts

Would be awasome if someone could help out :)

[image: fail with any wrong data]
[image: typescript version]

Answer (score 0):

this vsc plugin helped, with TypescriptReact v3.8.0 dev (20191231) working again

plugin/extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next

Comment: that's why I stay away from it, you end up fighting your toolchain all the time.